# Driver not showing in /sys/bus tree

Tags: linux, drivers, usb

I'm trying to bind the "rt3572sta" to a USB device that previously had the "rt2800usb" driver bound to it. I ran this:

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo [device-bus-id] > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/unbind"
```

Where `[device-bus-id]` was 1-7. I then went to bind it to the "rt3572sta" driver, but for some reason that was not in `/sys/bus/usb/drivers`.

How do I make it show up?

Comment: Is the module loaded? `modprobe rt3572sta`

Comment: Yes, it is. lsmod shows it as loaded, and I have already ran modprobe rt3572sta to make sure.